# Mail attachment using Swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an email with an attachment (upload) using swiftmailer:

HTML:

```
                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-contact email-form"> 

                                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">       
                                    <input type="file" name="fileatt" />


                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="send-form" value="Send Form">

                            </form>
```

PHP:

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    $messageText .= ucfirst($key).": ".$value."\n\n";

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('A message')


$message->attach(
Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['fileatt']['name'])
);

  ->setFrom(array($_POST['email'] => $_POST['name']))
  ->setTo(array('xxx' => 'Timo de Vries'))->setBody($messageText);

try{
    echo($mailer->send($message));
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
exit;
}
```

But I alwas get an server error. If I leave out the line

```
$message->attach(
Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['fileatt']['name'])
);
```

the message is sent withour a problem.
Somebody has an idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Simple: files require a post method and yours does not have one and defaults to a get.

Comment: I tried
$attachfile=$_POST["fileatt"];
$message->attach(
Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['fileatt']['name'])
);
but without any effect...

Comment: You can't use POST, you need to use FILES. Again, add a "post" method to your form. I.e.: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-contact email-form" method="post">`